# DigitalOcean Ubuntu Droplet Maven Installation

Tags: maven-3

I have a DigitalOcean droplet that runs Ubuntu 20.04. I want to install maven on my system but I need different configurations for each user so I just wanted to download binaries and set it up manually for each user.

But when I try to download the file with the command below this happens.

```
$ wget https://dlcdn.apache.org/maven/maven-3/3.8.4/binaries/apache-maven-3.8.4-bin.tar.gz
--2021-12-14 09:09:43--  https://dlcdn.apache.org/maven/maven-3/3.8.4/binaries/apache-maven-3.8.4-bin.tar.gz
Resolving dlcdn.apache.org (dlcdn.apache.org)... 2a04:4e42::644, 151.101.2.132
Connecting to dlcdn.apache.org (dlcdn.apache.org)|2a04:4e42::644|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 503 Backend unavailable, connection timeout
2021-12-14 09:09:44 ERROR 503: Backend unavailable, connection timeout.
```

Funny thing is I got the same error when I am connected to my server's vpn and try to download binaries from the browser but when I disconnected from the vpn I was able to download it. I suppose DigitalOcean is blocking the traffic somehow.

My question is; how am I gonna download the binaries directly? I don't want to use apt since it downloads all the related packages (somewhere around 170 mbs) but the binaries are only 8 mbs.

Comment: Also: this is the output of ping for mirror list site
ping: apache.org/mirrors/: Name or service not known

Comment: Problem is on THEIR end so this is not a question we can fix for you.  https://dlcdn.apache.org/maven/maven-3/3.8.4/binaries/ shows the file but it does not download it.

Comment: I see. I was guessing that but couldn't be sure. How can one be sure about it? And also why do you think they do that?